# How do i retrieve these files from my GitHub codespace?

Tags: git, github

I recently got a GitHub education account and started using GitHub codespaces, and also found out that it's still limited to 180 core hours.
After I inevetrably found out, I could no longer access the files that were added to the `.gitignore` file. These included some secret key's, so i cannot remove them from the `.gitignore` file to push them to the hub.
Is there any way that i can still access these files, or do I just need to wait on a restock of core hours.